# Office 365 tenant of dev subscription to develop Add in

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins

Our customer requested one POC development to move his product into Office 365 Excel add in. Later he plans to sell it to the external customers.

I cannot find any clear and up to date information, do I need as a developer to have an Office Developer subscription?

I've signed up for the Office Developer Program and received an email "To help you get started, we are giving you a one year, FREE subscription for an Office 365 Developer tenant"

Can I use it for my POC development? What are the restrictions if any? Or should I purchase any license /subscription?

Comment: This is not a programming question; you should read EULA or licencing agreement

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question.

Comment: @j08691, I think it's still a fine question -- it's about the getting started experience.  I would rather have more people try to get started and perhaps even ask slightly-off-topic questions, then be confused and decide to not code Office Add-ins at all...

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft I'm not saying it's not a fine question; it's just off-topic for SO. There may be another SE site better suited for it.

Answer (score 0):

To develop Office Add-ins, all you need is to have a copy of Office 2016 or (ideally) Office 265.  The two differ in that the latter is a subscription-based always-evergreen installation of Office which you can use across multiple devices -- and by being evergreen, you will see a bunch of new APIs and functionality and bug fixes within it.

Having an Office 365 Developer Tenant is one way of obtaining such subscription (and would also allow you to have a SharePoint site and an Exchange server, which you would need for developing SharePoint apps for Outlook add-ins).  But for purposes of building an Excel/Word/PPT/Project add-in, you just need access to an installed version of Office -- which might be through your personal Office 365 subscription or Office 365 for Business.

Note that to submit to the store, as per https://dev.office.com/officestore/docs/submit-to-the-office-store, you will need to register as an app developer (which is different from having an O365 dev tenant).  When you follow the "Register as an app developer" link, you will see:

> A developer account lets you submit apps and add-ins to Microsoft marketplaces, including the Windows Store, Office Store, Azure Marketplace, and more to come.
>
> ...
>
> Individual accounts cost approximately $19 USD, and company accounts cost approximately $99 USD (the exact amounts may vary depending on your country or region). This is a one-time registration fee and no renewal is required.

So, this is different from an Office 365 Developer Tenant, and is one-time registration for any Microsoft-based store submission.

You can read more about the differences between the different Office flavors/version in the prerequisites section of the e-book "[Building Office Add-ins using Office.js](https://leanpub.com/buildingofficeaddins/)".  Full disclosure: I am the author of said book, but I can pretty well guarantee you will find a lot of useful material there, not just about getting started with the right prerequisites, but also about the Office.js patterns in general.